# Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled

Tags: netbeans, spring, spring-boot, build

Si creo el projecto spring desde NetBeans o https://start.spring.io/ no lo puede ni desde ese IDE o Intellij, de un momento a otro me generar el error del titulo. Si corro el projecto en Debugging tambien genera el error, exepto en modo Clean and Build el proceso es correcto.

Solo tengo el archivo principal:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Ejemplo01Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Ejemplo01Application.class, args);
                
                System.out.println("******** Hellow World *************");
    }

}
```

El archivo application.properties, es vacio o con esta información igual genera el mismo error, adjunto 2 opciones como lo tenia configurado y ninguno funciono:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ejemplo
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
```

Este la otra configuracion que igual no funciona:

```
server.contextPath=/ejemplo01
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ejemplo
spring.datasource.username=jose
spring.datasource.password=jose
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

El archivo porn.xml tiene esta configuracion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ejemplo01</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ejemplo01</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Realice los ajuste que encontre a soluciones en estos link, pero tampoco se soluciono:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41738621/error-starting-applicationcontext-to-display-the-auto-configuration-report-re-r

https://programmerclick.com/article/97631837725/

He mirado videos de youtube y tampoco dan ninguna soluciono, verifique las respuesta anteriormente obtenida en esta web y tampoco me funcionan.

Adjunto por último el resultado de compilación:

```
-----------------------< com.example:ejemplo01 >------------------------
Building ejemplo01 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
--------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) @ ejemplo01 ---

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.3)

2021-08-19 18:32:59.139  INFO 270943 --- [           main] c.e.ejemplo01.Ejemplo01Application       : Starting Ejemplo01Application using Java 11.0.12 on debian with PID 270943 (/home/yamid/CRUD_ANGULAR_SPRING_MYSQL/CRUD_Sencillo/ejemplo01/target/classes started by yamid in /home/yamid/CRUD_ANGULAR_SPRING_MYSQL/CRUD_Sencillo/ejemplo01)
2021-08-19 18:32:59.142  INFO 270943 --- [           main] c.e.ejemplo01.Ejemplo01Application       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-08-19 18:33:00.273  INFO 270943 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-08-19 18:33:00.311  INFO 270943 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 7 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-08-19 18:33:01.154  INFO 270943 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-08-19 18:33:01.173  INFO 270943 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-08-19 18:33:01.173  INFO 270943 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.50]
2021-08-19 18:33:01.297  INFO 270943 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-08-19 18:33:01.297  INFO 270943 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2018 ms
2021-08-19 18:33:01.625  INFO 270943 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-08-19 18:33:01.694  INFO 270943 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.32.Final
2021-08-19 18:33:01.887  INFO 270943 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-08-19 18:33:02.009  INFO 270943 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-08-19 18:33:02.561  INFO 270943 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-08-19 18:33:02.593  INFO 270943 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2021-08-19 18:33:03.277  INFO 270943 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-08-19 18:33:03.290  INFO 270943 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-08-19 18:33:03.360  WARN 270943 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-08-19 18:33:03.831  WARN 270943 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
2021-08-19 18:33:03.834  INFO 270943 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-08-19 18:33:03.837  INFO 270943 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-08-19 18:33:03.852  INFO 270943 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2021-08-19 18:33:03.854  INFO 270943 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-08-19 18:33:03.870  INFO 270943 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-08-19 18:33:03.891 ERROR 270943 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.example.ejemplo01.Ejemplo01Application.main(Ejemplo01Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:229) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:43) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:243) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:282) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:213) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1075) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: La dirección ya se está usando
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:447) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:227) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:272) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1208) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1294) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:614) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1072) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
    ... 20 common frames omitted

Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:764)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:711)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  7.511 s
Finished at: 2021-08-19T18:33:04-05:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) on project ejemplo01: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: El mensaje `Caused by: java.net.BindException: La dirección ya se está usando` . O corriste ese mismo servicio antes y no lo has detenido del todo, o hay algo más usando el mismo puerto. Revisa los procesos en ejecución y detén el que no debería estar corriendo (o usa otro puerto)

Answer (score 0):

Encontra el error y es cambiar en el achivo application.properties cambiar el puerto de servicio Tomcat, ya que el puerto que toma por defecto 8080 ya lo esta utilizando Apache, en esta ocasión lo deje en 8090 tambien lo puedes dejar en 0 y el buscara el que este disponible.

```
server.port = 8090

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ejemplo
spring.datasource.username=rickg
spring.datasource.password=rickg
```

Answer (score 0):

Me salía el mismo error hasta que recargué el proyecto.

Click derecho en la `aplicación` y la opción: `reload from disk`

También, en el archivo `pom.xml`, dale click derecho y la opción:

```
Maven/reload project
```

Asimismo, puedes probar también:

```
Click derecho en pom.xml-> maven/Download Sources and Documentation
```

Si el error persiste:

- verifique que su ip tenga permisos para acceder al servidor
- verifique que está en el entorno adecuado: desarrollo, pruebas, producción
- Verifique si tiene todas las librerías disponibles en las clases.

Espero le haya sido de ayuda, buen día comunidad, Dios les bendiga.